# Upload a video on youtube using my website

Tags: video, upload, youtube, video-processing

I am creating an application where user will upload video and that video will upload directly on youtube on my account.

How will I achieve these?

I got issue:-

```
com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Premature end of file.
```

---

```
<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'><error><domain>GData</domain><code>ParseException</code><internalReason>Premature end of file.</internalReason></error></errors>
```

In below two lines

```
String uploadUrl = "http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads";
VideoEntry createdEntry = service.insert(new URL(uploadUrl), newEntry);
```

My code:-

```
private String uploadYoutube() throws MalformedURLException, IOException, ServiceException {
            String uProjectName = DBConnection.ytprojectName;
            String uName=DBConnection.gmailId;
            String uPassword=DBConnection.gmailPassword;
            String apiKey = DBConnection.ytApi;
            String filename = null;


        YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(uProjectName, apiKey);
        service.setUserCredentials(uName, uPassword);
        VideoEntry newEntry = new VideoEntry();
        YouTubeMediaGroup mg = newEntry.getOrCreateMediaGroup();
        mg.setTitle(new MediaTitle());


        mg.getTitle().setPlainTextContent(filename);
        mg.setDescription(new MediaDescription());
        mg.getDescription().setPlainTextContent(filename);

        mg.setDescription(new MediaDescription());
        mg.addCategory(new MediaCategory(YouTubeNamespace.CATEGORY_SCHEME, "Video"));
        mg.setKeywords(new MediaKeywords());
        mg.getKeywords().addKeyword("StudentResumeVideo");

        mg.setPrivate(false);
        mg.addCategory(new MediaCategory(YouTubeNamespace.DEVELOPER_TAG_SCHEME, "mydevtag"));
        mg.addCategory(new MediaCategory(YouTubeNamespace.DEVELOPER_TAG_SCHEME, "anotherdevtag"));
        String uploadUrl = "http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads";
            VideoEntry createdEntry = service.insert(new URL(uploadUrl), newEntry);
            if (createdEntry.isDraft()) {
                YtPublicationState pubState = createdEntry.getPublicationState();

                if (pubState.getState() == YtPublicationState.State.PROCESSING) {
                    String cleanedUrl = createdEntry.getHtmlLink().getHref().replace("/watch?v=", "/embed/");
                    cleanedUrl = cleanedUrl.substring(0, cleanedUrl.indexOf("&feature"));
                    return cleanedUrl;
                } else if (pubState.getState() == YtPublicationState.State.REJECTED) {

                } else if (pubState.getState() == YtPublicationState.State.FAILED) {

                }
            }

        return null;
    }
```